# passwordless ssh authentication using active directory

Tags: ssh, active-directory, kerberos, ssh-keys

Our current infrastructure uses ssh keys for passwordless login to our Linux servers.
As our infrastructure grows, managing these authorised keys is getting harder.

As we also have an Active Directory (AD) server, I would like to authenticate the users over ssh using this mechanism, but maintain the passwordless nature of ssh keys.

Is it possible to authenticate the users over ssh without password, using some AD mechanism?

Comment: take a look to https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open/wiki: It supports Kerberos, NTLM, and SPNEGO authentication

Answer (score 7):

This is usually done via SSH key certificates in order to keep the password-less nature and at the same time have a Central Authority that can be trusted to generate new certificates for each account.

LDAP/Active directory use on login is not advised - apart from having to use passwords, it also becomes a single point of failure for access to any system it manages.

See [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Using_OpenSSH_Certificate_Authentication.html) on how to do this and also [Facebook's good write up on their use of certificate authentication with SSH](https://code.facebook.com/posts/365787980419535/scalable-and-secure-access-with-ssh/).

Comment: The 2nd paragraph has some logical failures. A CA is no less of a SPOF than AD is. That's the nature of authoritative services. That's why you usually deploy them in clusters.

Comment: Yeah, they have different mechanisms. Regardless, what happens if your CA root cert is compromised (or expires, for that matter)? Bingo. All certs become useless. SPOF at its finest. To fight this, you can use cross-signing. And a CA cross-sign is pretty much the same as an AD cluster.

Comment: Already signed certificates have to be revoked or expire, they do not automatically become 'useless'. Perhaps go through some use cases in practice first - lot of misconceptions in these comments.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**

This is a good article explaining how to do this.
[Storing SSH keys in Active Directory for easy deployment](https://blog.laslabs.com/2016/08/storing-ssh-keys-in-active-directory/)

Basically, it will allow people to post their public keys to your Active Directory and then you can set up a cron script on your servers to fetch a copy of the public keys every 5 minutes or so.

**Option 2**

You could also use a file server that has all your keys and get each server to fetch from there using a cron script. Obviously, you need a way to verify each key's authenticity especially if you are using FTP or some other insecure protocol. This could be achieved using GPG. You could have a company master GPG key that signs all the employee keys.

Personally, I like option 2 the best because I think it is more secure, but either method should work. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to reduce the problem to an already solved one by

1. Use active directory to authenticate without password and establish an HTTPS connection using Kerberos. The [Dzone Tutorial **Configuring Tomcat 7 Single Sign-on with SPNEGO**](https://dzone.com/articles/do-not-publish-configuring-tomcat-single-sign-on-w) might be a good starting point for that approach.
2. Wrap SSH into the https-protocol like, see section **Wrapping SSH in HTTP(S)** at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190490/how-to-use-ssh-over-http-or-https

Answer (score 0):

I use this kind of process :
https://signmykey.io/

But sorry I'm just a user of it, I didn't find to install it in my company.
But the documentation seems clear.